# Philips Hue command limitation

Tags: api, philips-hue

First of all I'm developing my own C# library for controlling Philips Hue, which means I'm not using the official SDK. (I'm guessing that the SDK will make sure you won't have any problems)

I'm a little confused about the limitation in the [Core concepts](http://www.developers.meethue.com/documentation/core-concepts) page in the API, which states:

> We can’t send commands to the lights too fast. If you stick to around 10 commands per second to the `/lights` resource as maximum you should be fine. For `/groups` commands you should keep to a maximum of 1 per second.

I intend to respect this limitation, but does the limitation still apply when you are performing GET requests on the `/lights` resource, or is it only for sending actual commands with PUT requests to `/lights/<id>/state` that change the state of the light? Same question goes for the `/groups` resource.

Also is it even possible to damage anything by sending too many requests, or will it just take longer to get all responses?

**Edit:**

My overall question is: How should I understand the API limitation?

A more specific sub-question is: Should I wait 100 ms before sending another `/lights` command, relative to when I received a response, or relative to when I sent the previous command?

Another sub-question is: Should I consider this limitation only when using PUT requests on e.g. `/lights/<id>/state`, or on all request types GET/PUT/POST/DELETE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if anything was changed in firmware updates, but I have discovered that the bridge might not be so simple as you would think, and that the API description isn't very clear.
I've done a little testing while running firmware `01009914`.

The bridge seems to have some kind of queue of incoming commands. I sent `{"bri":254}` to a group 9 times and 1 final command of `{"bri":1}`. From the first command to when the light is actually dimmed, takes roughly 3-4 seconds. Each time I sent a command the bridge replied almost instantly with `success` token.

I did the same small tests sending other commands, 10 of each JSON object:

- `{"bri":254}` 3-4 seconds
- `{"on":true, "bri":254}` 6-7 seconds
- `{"on":true, "bri":254, "alert":"none", "effect":"none"}` 12-13 seconds

This actually shows that each change of attributes takes roughly 0.3 seconds for the bridge to handle.

I will claim that for each attribute we change, the bridge takes about 300 ms to finish, and the limitation of commands should be understood as: As long as you stick with changing one attribute of a group each second, you should be fine.

*Note:* I only tried with one group consisting of three lights, and I don't know if the bridge actually does have a queue of incoming commands, and in case it does have a queue, I don't know what the limit of items in it is.

**Edit:**

Now we have some official clarification of the [Hue System Performance](http://www.developers.meethue.com/documentation/hue-system-performance).

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly certain that the 10 commands per second is a guideline to prevent failure of the Bridge, and is a technical limitation of the hardware. Any more than that and you're apt to overload the bridge. I believe this applies to commands as well as requests.

Both approaches are reasonable. For laziness' sake, you could wait for 100ms to send a response, but I would only rely on this method if you don't plan on any other interactions with the Bridge.

I consider this limitation on all request types.

Comment: It might also be a legal limit. Philips Hue uses ZigBee Light Link as its RF technology. While Light Link uses a frequency of 2.4GHz, other ZigBee modules also use 868 MHz and 915 MHz. In Germany, sending on the 868 MHz frequencies is limited to 1% of time (or using "listen before talk"), see [the fhem wiki](http://www.fhemwiki.de/wiki/1%25_Regel) (german, [translated](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=de&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fhemwiki.de%2Fwiki%2F1%2525_Regel)).

Answer (score 2):

You won't damage anything if you send commands too fast. However, if you send commands too fast the bridge might become unresponsive and/or some messages can be ignored.

When it comes to the bridge, the way I think of it is that the bridge is more or less single threaded, so it works best if you make sure you don't send the next command before the previous one has returned.
In practice we've found that this works much better than waiting a fixed time between each request. In fact, you can pretty much send commands as fast as you want as long as you wait for the previous one to finish.

When you send a command to the bridge, the bridge has to then send it to the lamps through Zigbee. Since it's a mesh network in some cases the message has to make a couple of hops from lamp to lamp before it reaches the target. Depending on how many lamps you have and how many hops the signal needs to take, this can take a while. Also, it's possible that some messages randomly take much longer than others.

In general the system is not designed to handle very fast changes, but if you keep the above in mind you can make many cool effects :)